# Implementing broadcast push notification using AWS Lambda?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-lambda

Hi I'm wondering if AWS lambda is good enough technology to send broadcast push notifications up to hundreds of thousands of devices.

I have already implemented a lambda function that sends push notification to APNS or FCM(The new GCM), but it's just 1:1.

But now I would like to send the same message to multiple devices--up to hundreds of thousands of push notifications--simultaneously.

I've been using Microsoft Azure Notifications Hub just for this, but I would like to graduate to directly rolling my own. Any advice on how I should go about this?

Comment: out of curiosity: what is missing in Firebase Topics that prevents you from using it to broadcast your msgs ?    https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini I still have to implement the logic for iOS, which means being able to broadcast to firebase topics does not make my life any easier.

Comment: Firebase is cross platform. This is the doc for iOS:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini what i meant was I don't want to rely on a 3rd party service to send broadcast pushes as much as possible. I know this is tricky for FireBase because Google made the boundary blurry by adding iOS support on top of their own GCM, but technically the iOS-facing push service can be considered "3rd party service", just like Azure Notification Hub is. I know for Android I must use it, but I prefer not to use it for iOS.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the explanation. If you change your mind and you need some feature in firebase topics, feel free to contact https://firebase.google.com/support

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html) for mobile push notifications. You can create a topic, then create endpoints (mobile devices) and subscribe all these endpoints to that topic. Once you send a notification to that topic, all the mobile devices get the notification.

Comment: Thanks, like I mentioned, I have already been using microsoft azure notification hub for something like this, and in case of azure they don't even have a topic limit (which sns does). But anyway, my question was NOT about looking for a new 3rd party push service, but a way to build this on my own. More specifically I wanted to know if I can just build a lambda function and send broadcast pushes in parallel (so i can easily move it to another hosting in case I don't want it to be on aws anymore)

Comment: By default there is 10.000.000 subscription limit per topic, which is very high and also it can be increased via a support ticket. I can understand that you don't want a vendor lock-in, but just consider that probably the price per hour of yourself which you will spend to implement and maintain this stuff is more expensive than what you'd pay to aws/azure/firebase.

Comment: I do understand that, that's why i've been using Azure. But I am trying to do this because there is a clear need for this on my end. Also SNS only supports up to 100,000 topics per account, and you have to request more when you reach the limit. This is pretty limiting. I have personally used all of the SNS/Azure/Firebase and have production apps running on them. I just would appreciate if I could get an answer about how I can build this myself.

Comment: If SNS limits seem to be very low to you (although you can lift those with customer support help) I am afraid that Lambda is also not a good fit for you. There is 100 parallel execution limit for Lambda and also it'll be very expensive to use it just to send notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Brodcasting a message to thousands of devices can be implemented in-house, but you need to pay attention to few edge cases including:

1. sometimes FCM or APNs service might return a temporary error. You need to keep track of which devices didn't receive the message and retry later.
2. retry later could mean retry after, 1 second, or 1 minute, 2 , 4 ...
   your service need to stay active all this time.
3. some tokens will become invalid (users uninstall the app). Your service need to keep track of these and clean your database
4. even if a token doesn't become invalid, it's a good practice to remove from your database the tokens for the devices that didn't log in your system in the last 2 or 3 months.

Due to the above constraints I don't think Lambda is the best platform to build such infrastructure.